# getting input with select

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, input

in my react application I wish to change the input to a select tag in my form , how can I do that?

```
<form className="form-maker" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   Type:
  <input name="inputType" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
</form>
```

in to this:

```
<select>
  <option value="text">text</option>
  <option value="color">color</option>
  <option value="date">date</option>
  <option value="email">email</option>
  <option value="tel">tel</option>
  <option value="number">number</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleChange` goes in the `<select />` element, similar to the `<input />`.

Here is a small running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "text" };

  onSelect = ({target}) => this.setState({value: target.value})

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
          <option value="text">text</option>
          <option value="color">color</option>
          <option value="date">date</option>
          <option value="email">email</option>
          <option value="tel">tel</option>
          <option value="number">number</option>
        </select>
        <div>{`Selectet Value is ${value}`}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

You will probably want an array of these values, so it will be easier to render the `<options />` and set the `selected` attribute.

Here is another example, this time with a different default value selected:

```js
const values = [
  "text", "color", "date", "email", "tel","number"
]

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "date" };

  onSelect = ({target}) => this.setState({value: target.value})

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
          {values.map(val => <option key={val} value={val} selected={val === value}>{val}</option>)}
        </select>
        <div>{`Selectet Value is ${value}`}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: I have another question, is there a way for me to reset the select tab after I submit? I entered an option that says: Please select a type, and I want after the submit to show it again

Comment: yeah, just set the state again

Comment: but the select is not connected to the state ( I used the first code snippet)

Comment: So this is an uncontrolled select. same as you have an uncontrolled input, where you are not setting the value, you can't reset it. read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components)